# Simplifying $\frac{1}{x^3+y^3} + \frac{1}{x^6+y^6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify: $$\frac{1}{x^3+y^3}  + \frac{1}{x^6+y^6}$$

I know $\frac {na}{nb} = \frac {a}{b}$.
But I also know $(\frac{a}{b})^2 =  \frac {a^2}{b^2} \neq \frac{a}{b}$

So how do I get the same denominator (go from $x^3+y^3$ to $x^6+y^6$) if I can't just square it, since that would change its value? And even if I did just square it, I would be left with an extra $2x^3y^3$, which is another problem I don't know how to handle. Any guidance on handling these type of problems would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Don't you think that this expression is simplified enough? We can press with sums of heterogeneous fractions a little further $\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}+x^{6}+y^{6}}{(x^{3}+y^{3})(x^{6}+y^{6})}$ but it doesn't look any nicer than what you wrote.

Comment: I agree wit A.P. though maybe it's part of a larger exercise where $x,y$ have a relation ? In which case there would possibly be simplification.

Comment: It makes sense to ask how to find the least common denominator (a reasonable problem with a nontrivial answer), though expressing the value as a single ratio of polynomials is not necessarily more concise or elegant.  Please edit to give more context for your efforts.

Answer (score -1):

How about if you let $x^3 = a$ and $y^3 = b$?

Then $x^3 + y^3 = a + b$ and $x^6 + y^6 = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Why not denoting the entire expression $a+b$ or even just $c$? Technically this answer should be a comment.

Comment: Well, tried doing this in me noggin and this is what happens: $\frac{a^2 + b^2 + a + b}{(a + b)(a^2 + b^2)}$ Can we now simplify it further?

Comment: @AgentSmith OK but when you plug back in for a,b what you defined them as, it is just what user A.P. noted in the comment. And I agree this is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: Ok. If that's what everyone says it is, then it is. So, what do I do? Delete the answer?